# abstract algebra , ideal of a ring of matrices .

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the ring,
$$
R =\{   \big( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{smallmatrix} \big)  : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z} \},
$$
prove that
$$
I =\{   \big( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 3k \end{smallmatrix} \big)  : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}
$$
is an ideal.

Is this ideal maximal? Yes, but how can i prove it? I know that the factor ring $R/I$ is isomorphic to Z3, which is a field, but I can't conclude that $I$ is maximal since $R$ is not commutative. (If R is commutative with unity then $R/I$ is a field iff $I$ is maximal). 
I tried to use the definition of maximal ideal, i.e., that there's no ideal between $R$ and $I$ apart from such ones, but I got lost.

Any help, please?

Comment: $I$ is not an additive subgroup.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is not a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication you need is true also for non-commutative rings with unity. Suppose $I \le R$ is an two-sided ideal such that $R/I$ is a field. Denote by $\pi \colon R \to R/I$ the projection. Let $J \le R$ be an ideal with $I \subsetneq J$. Then, the ideal $\pi[J]$ ($\pi$ is onto) is the whole field (as $\pi[J]\supsetneq (0)$). So, there is $j \in J$ with $\pi(j) = 1+I$ or $j+I = 1+I$. Hence, for some $i \in I$ $j + i = 1$, or
$$ 1 = i+j \in J. $$
Hence $J = R$.

Comment: by " the ideal generated by π[J] " , you mean the image of J under π ? which is an ideal of R/I if π is onto ?

Comment: Yes, you are right of course, $\pi[J]$ is an ideal ...

Comment: but π is not onto . so π[J] is nt an ideal .

Comment: $\pi$ is onto ... given $r+I \in R/I$, then $\pi(r) = r+I$.

Comment: That's right . I'm mistaken .Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that any ideal containing $I$ along with any element not in $I$ contains $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$.

Comment: I thaught of it too ,but i got nowhere . I started by , any elements of the ring can have 3 forms . c=3k or c=3k+1 or c=3k+2 . when c= 3k this gives me the ideal I . so an element in an ideal containing I and nt in I has 2 forms . I tried to get a unit or a unity but i couldn't .

Comment: Take $M$ not in the ideal.  Let $1$ denote the identity element.  In the $3k+1$ case, note that $M - 1$ is in $I$.  In the $3k+2$ case, note that $M + 1$ is in $I$.

Comment: I'm not following . suppose I≤J≤R , where I⊊J . then we have M not in the ideal I . I thaught we need to show 1 is in J ??

Comment: Right. In case 1, we show $M - 1$ is in $I$, so that $1 = M - (M - 1)$, which means that $1$ is in $J$.

Answer (score 0):

you mean I to be the set of upper triangular matrices with a_44=3c, c is an integer. Otherwise the set you have given is not closed even under addition. Assuming this, then I is maximal by "brute force". For let (a,b,0,c) be any matrix in R and let c be not divisible by 3. Now c=1 or 2 mod 3. If c=1 mod 3 then we can find (x,y,0,3d) in I such that 
(a,b,0,c)+(x,y,0,3d)=(a+x,b+y,0,c+3d)=(1,0,0,1). While if c=2 mod 3 then c^2=1 mod 3 and we can find (x,y,0,3d) in I such that (x,y,0,3d)+(a,b,0,c)^2=(x,y,0,3d)+(a^2,ab+bc,0,c^2)=(1,0,0,1). Thus adjoining the matrix (a,b,0,c) to I generates the whole ring and so I is maximal.

Comment: what's brute force ? you used it so we have  (a,b,0,c) in I then (1,0,0,1) is in I ?